# How to declare a function which creates an object which will never be null?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, nullptr

I have a function which creates an object QMenu (in heap)

```
QMenu* createMenu(QWidget* parent); // parent will takes ownership of the menu
```

The function will never return a null pointer. But I think the declaration don't tell the point because it returns a pointer. Thus when using the method, I need

```
if (QMenu* m = createMenu(parent))
    m->...
```

which is annoying. If it returns a reference, it tells the point.

```
QMenu& createA(QWidget* parent);
```

I never see code declares this way. Is this okay? Is there any better declaration for the point?

Comment: The reference version doesn't work because you can't return a reference to a local object. And if your function does something like `return *new X;` then it is more confusing than the original version because the caller has to remember to do `delete &m;` at some point

Comment: Maybe you could document your intent with a `throw` specification on the `createMenu` function, and perhaps even a comment that says "Returns a valid QMenu, or throws a FooException"

Comment: Returning a local object's pointer is also nonsense. I think the word "Create" conventionally means to new an object on heap.

Comment: I was suggesting returning a `new`'d object, and saying that expecting the caller to do `delete &m;` afterwards is bad design (but expecting them to do `delete m;` is OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to return a created object by reference, if the function makes its own arrangements for ownership of that object's lifetime.

One big example of a function that does this: `V& std::map<K,V>::operator[](const K&);`.

Answer (score 2):

Just document that it doesn't return null. Not exactly very high-tech as a solution, but you'll see that it works great in practice.

Since it's then clear that your function doesn't return null, you don't have to write:

```
if (QMenu* m = createMenu(parent))
    m->...
```

You just write:

```
QMenu* m = createMenu(parent);
m->...
```

Think about it: either you need the `if` check in some form -- but then it's not true that the function never returns null.

Or the function really never, ever returns null. Then the `if` check is useless.

That being said, you can still add an assertion there to be extra safe:

```
QMenu* m = createMenu(parent);
assert(m != nullptr); // if you use C++11; otherwise assert(m != 0);
m->...
```

This means as much as *"If m is null, then my own code is messed up and the program is wrong. If that happens, please quit the program ASAP!"*

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and clearest way would be to return a value:

```
A createA();
```

Usually, if you need to allocate resources on "the heap", a good strategy is to design `A` such that it handles those resources itself.

Comment: This way I think it still need to handle A's resources which never tell the resources is null or not.

Comment: Actually a nice answer - omitting all of these memory leaking designs.

Comment: @user1899020 Impossible to say without more information. What is `A`'s responsibility? Why do you need to allocate "in the heap"?

Comment: @juanchopanza I edit my questions with more details.

Comment: If `A` is not copyable this won't work. I say this as I suspect the classes OP is asking about are GUI components that aren't supposed to be copied.

Comment: @MattMcNabb when this was posted there was no hint that the types could be non-copyable. I answered the question that was asked.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Not a problem, as you can easily return a proxy (wrapping a `std::weak_ptr` for example if it should not own anything).